# Cucable plugin: How can I avoid running the '[CUCABLE:FEATURE].feature' (java template file)?

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

Following is my cucumber template java file.

```
    package some.template;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
//import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import cucumber.api.testng.CucumberFeatureWrapper;
import cucumber.api.testng.PickleEventWrapper;
import cucumber.api.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner;
//import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.testng.IRetryAnalyzer;
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;


//@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        glue = "com.fifa.stepdefs",
        features = {"target/parallel/features/[CUCABLE:FEATURE].feature"},
        plugin = {"json:target/cucumber-report/[CUCABLE:RUNNER].json"}
)

public class CucableJavaTemplate implements IRetryAnalyzer {

    private int count = 0;
    private static int maxTry = 3;

    @Override
    public boolean retry(ITestResult iTestResult) {
        if (!iTestResult.isSuccess()) {  ;//Check if test not succeed
            if (count < maxTry) {                            //Check if maxtry count is reached
                count++;                                    //Increase the maxTry count by 1
                iTestResult.setStatus(ITestResult.FAILURE);  //Mark test as failed
                return true;                                 //Tells TestNG to re-run the test
            } else {
                iTestResult.setStatus(ITestResult.FAILURE);  //If maxCount reached,test marked as failed
            }
        } else {
            iTestResult.setStatus(ITestResult.SUCCESS);      //If test passes, TestNG marks it as passed
        }
        return false;
    }
    private TestNGCucumberRunner testNGCucumberRunner;

    @BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void setUpClass() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Before Scenario ****");
        testNGCucumberRunner = new TestNGCucumberRunner(this.getClass());
    }

    @Test(groups = "cucumber", description = "Runs Cucumber Scenarios", dataProvider = "scenarios",retryAnalyzer = CucableJavaTemplate.class)
    public void scenario(PickleEventWrapper pickleEvent, CucumberFeatureWrapper cucumberFeature) throws Throwable {
        testNGCucumberRunner.runScenario(pickleEvent.getPickleEvent());
    }

    @DataProvider
    public Object[][] scenarios() {
        return testNGCucumberRunner.provideScenarios();
    }

    @AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void tearDownClass() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("After Scenario ****");
        testNGCucumberRunner.finish();
    }
}
```

When I run mvn clean verify, the following happens:

1. Scenario in feature files are broken into multiple scenarios and
   individual runners are generated
2. Tests are run. But before the actual tests are run, cucumber-testng also tries to run '[CUCABLE:FEATURE].feature' and fails with error:

[Utils] [ERROR] [Error] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a file or directory: /projectpath/target/parallel/features/[CUCABLE:FEATURE].feature

- How can I avoid running the '[CUCABLE:FEATURE].feature'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <skipTests>true</skipTests>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

I think I figured this out. Added the above plugin and those tests are now skipped.